# A martini before and a cigarette after

Tags: meaning-in-context, numbers

I read a quote from an unnamed source:

> I asked my friend, "what are your three favorite pleasures in life?" and she replied, "A martini before and a cigarette after."

As far as I can tell, a cigarette and a martini are only two things, so what's going on here?

Comment: the thing in-between before and after

Comment: I've used the same line substituting a different cocktail and 'and Eggs Benedict after'.

Comment: There are two types of people: those who can extrapolate from an incomplete data set.

Comment: There are 10 types of people: those who understand binary and those who don't. But, in this case, interpolation is all that's required.

Answer (score 58):

The implication is that the martini is before sex and the cigarette after.

Comment: Smoking after sex is a common trope. Two people in bed smoking is used in films (often comedies) to imply that sexual intercourse had occurred. Alcohol has been used to lower inhibitions which leads to activity.

Comment: It should be noted it's a -dated- trope... it's rare to see any smoking at all on TV or films these days outside of characters where unhealthy lifestyles are being accentuated.  Old films may keep it familiar enough in reruns though.

Comment: It's rare to see people order martinis nowadays also. Although smoking in films is  common enough, still. It's just that not every single actor does it, smoking that is.

Comment: @Tom22 Regardless of whether the trope is dated, the practice — from my experience living in New York City over the last 5 years — is still common.  I'd assume it's also still common in other high-stress _(where smoking/vaping is common)_ & high-dating-activity _(where sex is common, natch)_ city areas around the world.

Comment: my grandfather, who wrote the column,  [Martinis](http://mcgowans.org/pubs/martinis/) would say the original poster _user237658_ was sufficiently incurious

Answer (score 0):

I think the quip means that her 3 favorite things are:

1) A martini before (having sex)

2) (Having sex)

3) A cigarette after (having sex)